# AAA Radius Privilege levels

Tags: aaa

I've setup a Windows 2012 Server R2 Radius server to commmunicate with CISCO IOS devices.

There are two categories of users: with just read only rights(shell:priv-lvl=1), and read/write (shell:priv-lvl=15).

The Router configuration on GNS3 is straightforward:

```
aaa authentication login VTY group RAD1 local
aaa authorization exec AUTH_VTY group RAD1 local if-authenticated

line vty 0 20
 login authentication VTY
 authorization exec AUTH_VTY
```

So, my goal is  to read only users allow to just read, to read/write users allow to do all.

but the situation is different. Users with (shell:priv-lvl=15) gets into privileged mode as it should. 
And users with (shell:priv-lvl=1) goes to operational mode (>) and after typing "enable" they goes into priviledge mode.

Is this a normal behaviour with Priviledge 1 - to be able to get to enable ? Maybe my problem is just to create the enable password, which is unknown for users with priviledge lvl 1 ?

Also the second question:

Do the if-authenticated command is needed ? could not figure point of that.

Thanks

EDIT:

configuration is here:

> ```
> aaa authorization exec AUTH_VTY group RAD1 local if-authenticated
> aaa authorization console
> aaa authentication login VTY group RAD1 local
> username labas privilege 15 password 0 labas
>
> line vty 0 20
> login authentication VTY
> authorization exec AUTH_VTY
>
> line con 0
> login authentication VTY
> authorization exec AUTH_VTY
>
> aaa group server radius RAD1
>  server-private 10.1.1.1 auth-port 1645 acct-port 1646 key 7 13171616021917
>
> enable secret labas
> ```

---

Here in config "if auth" is added but it works exactly the same as if there's no keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "enable" command is a level 1 command. If you don't want your users to execute it, the simplest way is not to give them the password.

Alternatively, you can configure command authorization, but that is significantly more complicated, especially with RADIUS.

The if-authenticated command is used with authorization.  It bypasses the authorization check.  It's often used as a backup if the AAA server is unavailable.

Comment: thank you. Regarding the 2nd question about the if-authentificated. After the user logs on using radius - and after logon radius server wents down - the cisco device doesnt initiates any request to radius, so still i dont understand the point of if-auth in Radius enviroment.

Comment: That's probably because you don't have AAA authorization enabled.  If you're only concerned with authenticating users -- that is, controlling who has access -- you're fine.  If you also want authorization -- that is, controlling what those users are allowed to do, then you need to configure AAA authorization.  That's where the command comes into play.   If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it as accepted so it doesn't keep popping up in the list looking for an answer.

Comment: thanks, i use authorization, tried both variants: with and without if-authentication. The results is the same. Even try to do catch the packets on wire shark, after logon to the device no radius packets are sent to the Radius even i do enable/disable commands. So i stil think that it's only for tacacs. I will mark as accepted.

Comment: Post your configuration so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: added to the first post